# trying to remove UTC timestamps from an array of date objects, and still return the dates

Tags: typescript

I'm fairly unfamiliar with typescript and wanted to see if anyone had a quick solution for removing or filtering out UTC times from date objects.

I have a program that is retrieving JSON objects with dates and only need the format (yyyy-mm-dd)

I've already sorted the objects chronologically using a sort comparator in a dateArray and just need to remove the time.

Thanks a bunch!

I've tried using DateTime.fromJSDate and running a function that returns year/month/day but I think I might need to iterate through the array either with a forEach() or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DatePipe` (https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

```
dateWithoutTime = new Date(datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```